# Snap UICollection View Cell to centre using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am implementing a Horizontal UICollectionView in Objective C. I want to snap the cell to the centre of the collection view as shown in image below. When an item is snapped to centre I want the items on left and right partially visible. How can I achieve this?

[image]

I have used custom IOCOllectionViewFlowLayout and override the

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
```

but its not working for me ,

```
CGFloat approximatePage = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.pageWidth;
    CGFloat currentPage = (velocity.x < 0.0) ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage);

    NSInteger flickedPages = ceil(velocity.x / self.flickVelocity);
    float pageWidth = self.pageWidth;
    if (flickedPages) {
        proposedContentOffset.x = flickedPages * self.pageWidth;
    } else {
        proposedContentOffset.x = currentPage * self.pageWidth;
    }
    return proposedContentOffset;
```

How to implement it using Objective C?

Comment: By snap you mean tapping on a desired cell?

Comment: No, while scrolling it should center to that cell.

Comment: You mean when user stops scrolling, while scrolling is bad ux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate with scrollViewWillEndDragging delegate of the UIViewController scroll view. Further reading here https://rolandleth.com/uicollectionview-snap-scrolling-and-pagination

Answer (score 0):

In this case when you need to be centered horizontally, you will need to implement delegate method `scrollViewWillEndDragging` as kirander mentioned. When you detect that user stopped scrolling, detect visible cell and put it on the center with this code: `projectSelectionCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)`